# Заголовок таблицы при скроле вверх/вниз должен оставаться на месте

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть таблица, сверху есть шапка. Надо, чтобы при прокрутки вниз, заголовок оставался на месте. [Вот таблица](http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/krNcp/). `position:fixed` не предлагать. Подскажите, как это сделать. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jGaVU/3/)

```js
var tbl = $('table');
var title = $('thead');
var titleClone = title.clone(true, true);
titleClone.prependTo(tbl).css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: tbl.offset().left,
    zIndex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#efefef'
}).hide();
title.find('th').each(function(i,el){
    titleClone.find('th:eq(' + i + ')').width($(el).width());
});

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > title.offset().top + title.height()){
        titleClone.show();
    } else {
        titleClone.hide();
    }
});

$('#doublescroll').scroll(function(){
    titleClone.css('left', - $(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
#doublescroll{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    overflow: auto;
    width:400px;
}
/*.top_scroll {
 height:20px;
 overflow-x:scroll;
}*/
.srav {
 margin:0 0 20px;
 padding:20px 0;
 color:#666;
}

.srav table {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.srav table th, .srav table td {
 padding:10px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.srav table td{
}
.srav table thead {
    
}
.srav table thead th {
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.srav table thead th a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.srav table thead th img {
 display:block;
 margin:15px auto 0;
}
.srav table thead td {
 background:#e9eded;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#489925;
}
.srav table tbody {
}
.srav table tbody th {
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align:middle;
 border-top:1px solid #333;
}
.srav table tbody td {
 vertical-align:middle;
 border-top:1px solid #333;
 border-left:1px solid #333;
}
.srav table tbody tr:first-child th, .srav table tbody tr:first-child td {
 border-top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="srav" id="doublescroll">
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><a href="#">Заголовок</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Заголовок</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Заголовок</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Заголовок</a></th>
     </tr>
     
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
<tr>
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr class="vert1">
      <th class="infohead">Графический ускоритель</th>
      <td>nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
      <td class="better">nVidea</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: А если ширина не 100% а определённая к примеру 400px, чтобы появлялся горизонтальный скрол, как сделать чтобы при прокрутки вниз та часть заголовка которая не влазит в эти 400px скрывалась

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/jGaVU/

Comment: @Karalahti, ну такие мелочи уже можно было бы и самому. [Смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jGaVU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите "рвать" таблицу на части при прокрутке страницы? Это конечно же возможно, но зачем? Просто вытащите заголовок таблицы за ее пределы - `<th> -> <div>`. А вот уже блок позиционируйте, как вам нужно + установите `position:fixed`.
Также можно обойтись одним лишь JS для сохранения постоянной позиции блока на странице( вместо фиксированного позиционирования ). Для этого достаточно обрабатывать прокрутку примерно таким образом:

```
pred = 0;

function f()
{
    if(pred==window.scrollY) return 0;
    pred = window.scrollY;
    $("#caption-block").css({"top":pred+"px"});
    }

window.setInterval(f,1);
```

Но второй способ можно назвать "быдлянским", потому что в CSS и так присутствует возможность установки фиксированной позиции.

Comment: Если сделать как по первому варианту то при fixed весь блок будит виден полностью, а у меня есть горизонтальный скрол и то что не влазит должно скрываться, при fixed не работат